# Set Audio Settings of MS Team Room/Conference From outside the App

Tags: c#, windowsiot

I am using MS Teams Rooms/Conference with Windows IOT, I want to know is there any way, we can set/change its Audio Settings of MS Teams Rooms App from outside it using C# or powershell,

Thanks in advance...

Right now I can set windows Audio Communication with the code only if Teams Rooms Is not running

```cs
// Create a new audio PolicyConfigClient
PolicyConfigClient client = new PolicyConfigClient();

client.SetDefaultEndpoint(deviceid, ERole.eCommunications);
```

After Set Audio Communication of windows, If i run it, MS Teams Room Revert it back to previous setting, SO how i can prevent it from resetting to previous setting,